# SwiftUI Shape Scale Size Such that HStack size does not increase

Tags: forms, swiftui, shapes, hstack

I'm trying to make the circles fit into the `HStack` such that the `HStack` size does not increase.
How can I make the circles fit without specifying a fixed frame?

```swift
struct ContentView: View {
    
    var body: some View {
        NavigationView {
            Form {
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.red)
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("Hello")
                }
                HStack {
                    Circle()
                        .fill(Color.blue)
                        .aspectRatio(1, contentMode: .fit)
                    Text("Hello")
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Circles]

Comment: HStack does not have own size, as well as circle, so could you please describe or sketch somehow what do you try to achieve?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a sample of various containers to chose from. SwiftUI will do all the layout, automatically handle rotations and device resolutions.

```
struct CirclesView: View {
    var body: some View {
        VStack(spacing: 0) {
            Label("Circles", systemImage: "circle").font(.system(size: 24, weight: .black, design: .rounded)).foregroundColor(.pink)
            HStack {
                Circle()
                    .foregroundColor(.yellow)
                    .frame(width: 32, height: 32)
                Text("This is a yellow circle")
                Spacer()
            }
            Circle()
                .foregroundColor(.orange)
                .shadow(radius: 10)
                .frame(width: 75)
            Divider()
            HStack {
                VStack {
                    Circle().foregroundColor(.blue)
                    Text("Blue").font(.title3)
                    HStack {
                        Circle().foregroundColor(.purple)
                        Text("Purple").font(.caption)
                    }
                }
                .padding()
                .background(Color.yellow)
                ZStack(alignment: Alignment(horizontal: .center, vertical: .center)) {
                    Circle().foregroundColor(.green)
                    Text("Green").foregroundColor(.primary)
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

[image: Circles View]

Comment: Nice! The topmost label was exactly what I was looking for.